# Send form values to db error

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to send data from an html form to a database using php, I keep getting `error unexpected ; in line 6`. I cant seem to find the exact cause.

This is the code of send.php:

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO sw5_green (firstname_r, lastname_r, vid, occupation, address, firstname_s, lastname_s, country, amount, currency) 
VALUES ('$_POST[post_firstname_r]', '$_POST[post_lastname_r]', '$_POST[post_vid]', '$_POST[post_occupation]', '$_POST[post_address]', '$_POST[post_firstname_s]', '$_POST[post_lastname_s]', '$_POST[post_country]', '$_POST[post_amount]', '$_POST[post_currency]')";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks :) It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `)` at the end of the statement. put `)` this before last `;`.

Try it,

```
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO sw5_green (firstname_r, lastname_r, vid, occupation, address, firstname_s, lastname_s, country, amount, currency) 
VALUES ('$_POST[post_firstname_r]', '$_POST[post_lastname_r]', '$_POST[post_vid]', '$_POST[post_occupation]', '$_POST[post_address]', '$_POST[post_firstname_s]', '$_POST[post_lastname_s]', '$_POST[post_country]', '$_POST[post_amount]', '$_POST[post_currency]')");
```

Comment: That's not quite in the right place. Your explanation is right but the code example is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing )**

Replace your code with query with this

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO sw5_green (firstname_r, lastname_r, vid, occupation, address, firstname_s, lastname_s, country, amount, currency) 
VALUES ('$_POST[post_firstname_r]', '$_POST[post_lastname_r]', '$_POST[post_vid]', '$_POST[post_occupation]', '$_POST[post_address]', '$_POST[post_firstname_s]', '$_POST[post_lastname_s]', '$_POST[post_country]', '$_POST[post_amount]', '$_POST[post_currency]'))";
```

Comment: You've copied the same mistake from Vinod VT 's answer. (which he has since corrected).

Comment: please just check the time, i just typing the answer and some one given it before few second than its not mean that it copy @SimonShirley

Comment: Granted, that may have been the case. The answers and comments were in rapid succession, but it did seem odd that it was exactly the same typo.

Comment: if i want to copy than i can just change the description, but when i typing the answer at that time there is no any answers, so i have given that ans .

Comment: I'm not going to get into a debate over when things were posted as it's counter-productive. However, I will leave you with one final thought - your code example still contains the typo and therefore will not solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

wrong syntax

> '$_POST[post_firstname_r]' should be $_POST['post_firstname_r']

Always escape your data before saving.